# DynamoDb Global Index query on date range key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am getting a type mismatch with the following code:

```
        var queryRequest = new QueryRequest
        {
            TableName = table,
            IndexName = "CreatedBy-Created-index",
            KeyConditionExpression = "CreatedBy = :createdBy",
            ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>
            {
                {":createdBy", new AttributeValue {S = filterTasksRequest.CreatedBy.ToLowerInvariant()}}
            }
        };
        if (filterTasksRequest.OnlyShowRecent)
        {
            var earliestDate =
                new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-10)).ToUnixTimeSeconds()
                    .ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            queryRequest.ExpressionAttributeValues[":fromDate"] = new AttributeValue
            {
                N = earliestDate
            };
            queryRequest.KeyConditionExpression +=
                $" AND Created > :fromDate";
        }
```

Error is

> One or more parameter values were invalid: Condition parameter type
>   does not match schema type --->
>   Amazon.DynamoDBv2.AmazonDynamoDBException: One or more parameter
>   values were invalid: Condition parameter type does not match schema
>   type

Without the date filter on the sort key it works ok

Comment: What is the data type of `fromDate` and any example values stored in that column to understand this better?

Comment: its an epoch written as a number e.g. `1535580290`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had created the index with the sort key `Created` as a string and not a number.